# SPFX - Get what permission group user has in modern?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

Is it possible too get the user security group? I can't seem to find any information about doing this in SPFX, just for current web and list...

It should be possible having a div that renders the webpart of they have permission else hide it ?

Kind regards

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "user security group"? Did you tried to call the REST-Endpoint `/api/Web/CurrentUser` and after that `/api/Web/GetUserById(<USERID>)/Groups` ?

Comment: Hi! I mean if they are part of Read group ,designer or admin. So on certain pages the designer should see additional webparts that the Readers can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the two REST-Endpoints suggested in my comment. First call to get the user ID and after that the second call to get the groups in which the user is member.

```
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse, ISPHttpClientOptions } from '@microsoft/sp-http'; 

var absoluteUri = this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl;

this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(absoluteUri + "/_api/Web/CurrentUser?$select=ID",  
SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)  
    .then((userResponse: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  
        userResponse.json().then((user: any) => {  
            var userId = user.Id;

            this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(absoluteUri + "/_api/Web/GetUserById(" + userId + ")/Groups",  
            SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)  
                .then((groupResponse: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  
                    groupResponse.json().then((groupsData: any) => {  
                        var groups = groupsData.value;

                        groups.forEach(group => {
                            if(group.Title == "TARGETGROUP") {
                                // DISPLAY DIV
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
        });
    });
```

You have to get the current Context from the WebPart. In my example I use a component and get the context from the properties (this.props.context).

Comment: Btw its possible to call groups from currentuser: `_api/Web/CurrentUser/Groups?$select=Title`

Comment: Ahh...! You are right ;-) We don't need to call two REST-Endpoints.

Comment: Saw @AndersAune comment now! Yea I also went with "/_api/Web/CurrentUser/Groups?$select=Title", nice to see that I did it the right way